# Remove gift options attribute in Magento 1.7 default attribute set

Tags: attributes, magento

When creating a product I don't want to see the "Gift options" and "Recurring profile".
When editing the Default attribute set I can move those groups to the unassigned attributes.
But after save and edit, they are there again.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do , if you do not want to see the "Gift options" and "Recurring profile".
You can delete it.
Step 1 :First move the inside attributes to another group (drag & drop).
Step 2 :Then you can delete it (viz Gift options & Recurring profile) by clicking 'Delete Selected Group'.

Comment: Ok this works. Moved them to 'Design' group and deleted the 2 groups. Guess these system attributes need to be somewhere in a group.